# How can I prevent WPF from clipping my image?

Tags: wpf, clipping

I am writing a WPF app that displays an image that is initially centered. The user can zoom in/out and move the image, which are implemented using `ScaleTransform` and `TranslateTransform`. That works great.

The problem is when the image is significantly bigger than the window, and the user moves the image or zooms out enough so that the entire image should be visible. The portion of the image that was originally hidden isn't rendered, and instead only the originally viewable part of the image is drawn.

Based on some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686170/wpf-image-control-clipping) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010187/wpf-image-stretch-to-fill-doesnt-stretch-to-the-bounds-of-its-parents), if I put my image inside of a `Canvas` that will cause the entire image to be rendered, and when moved it will be rendered correctly. The problem is that I don't want my image to be in a `Canvas`, since that prevents any other layout from occurring - the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties are ignored (so the image is no longer centered), and I need to implement an option that will draw the image as large as possible to fill the entire area of the window which no longer works (setting the `Stretch` property to `UniformToFill` doesn't do anything).

Currently the two transforms are set to the `RenderTransform` property. If I use `LayoutTransform` instead, the entire image is drawn, but this also prevents the user from moving any portion of the image off the edge of the window (which is behavior that I would like to keep).

How can I tell WPF to always render the entire image without using a `Canvas` or a `LayoutTransform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not using a TranslateTransform but instead rely on the ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <Grid>
      <Image Source="blabla">
          <Image.LayoutTransform>
              <ScaleTransform />
          </Image.LayoutTransform>
      </Image>
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The ScrollViewer gives the Image infinite space to expand, the entire image will be rendered. The Grid forces a centered layout while still allowing the image to expand. If you don't like the scrollbars to control the translate then you can hide them and roll your own solution.

LayoutTransform is definetely the way to go, so that the image's actual size in pixels (based on the zoom) is properly reflected onto your window.

Comment: That does seem to work really well. One thing which doesn't work (that I admittedly forgot to mention in the question - sorry!) is that my image has a `RenderTransformOrigin` set to `0.5, 0.5` so that zooming operates on the center of the image. With the `ScrollViewer` zooming in ends up focusing on the top left corner of the image. Is there some way to force the scaling to operate on the center of the image in this case?

Comment: Andy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447114/how-to-keep-area-of-canvas-centered-in-a-scrollviewer-when-zoomed-in-or-out-and should answer your question.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work very well. The only change I had to make was to change the scroll offset in response to OnScrollChanged() for the ScrollViewer, since in my case the scroll info hadn't updated yet and I was getting some strange results. Thanks for the help. :)